# Probability Poisson distribution

Tags: probability

any idea how to answer this? :( thanks.

The number of cars appearing in a car park follows a Poisson distribution with a mean of 10 cars per hour. Find the probability of there being:

(a) Exactly 5 cars in a 30 minute interval,

(b) At most 3 cars in a 10 minute interval,

(c) More than 4 cars in a 15 minute interval,

(d) Exactly 1 cars in each of three consecutive 5 minute intervals.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I don't understand what to do to even make an attempt to be honest :(

Comment: Look at the orange key box in http://www3.ul.ie/~mlc/support/Loughborough%20website/chap5/5_3.pdf ; for instance, **(a)**: the number of cars X in a 30-minute interval follows a $\operatorname{Poi}(\lambda)$ distribution with average rate (mean) $\lambda = 10/2 = 5$. Hence, $$ \mathbb{P}\{X=5\} = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^5}{5!} = e^{-5} \frac{5^5}{5!}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the resource Clement, I will read that then try do the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$10$ cars per hour is $10/4 = 2.5$ cars per $15$ minutes.

The probability that more than $4$ cars arrive in a $15$-minute interval is $1$ minus the probability that $3$ or fewer arrive.  The probability that $3$ or fewer arrive is the probability that the number that arrive is the probability that the number of such cars is either $0$ or $1$ or $2$ or $3$.  To find the exact probability that exactly $3$ cars arrive, when the average is $2.5$ just plug in $3$ and $2.5$ into the formula in the appropriate places.  And similarly for $2$, $1$, and $0$.